# deselect all jquery multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select, deselect

I use [this multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic) and I want to use ***deselect all*** method using jquery. How can I do it

Comment: So your question is how to reset all multiselects, right???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `uncheckAll` function of `multiselect` like this:

```
$("select").multiselect('uncheckAll');
```

Also, keep in mind, you don't want to deselect all select tags in your page, so you have to use a selector using `data` or `class` or `name` attributes for the select tag you're targeting.

Comment: Just in case not all `select` elements on page are jq UI multiselect ones, this would be better selector: `$("select:data(echMultiselect)")`

Comment: @A.Wolff You're right. As OP didn't really give any code to work on, I figured they have got that part figured out. I will edit the answer to include this bit.